# By knowing $1 = 1^{-1} \mod p$ for a prime $p$, why can we obtain multiplicative inverse of $i$ for i = 2,...,p-1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

By knowing $1 = 1^{-1} \mod p$ for a prime $p$, why can we obtain multiplicative inverse of $i$ for i = 2,...,p-1?

In particular, why does the following work?

$$
i^{-1} \mod p = p - ((p \mod i)^{-1}\mod p)  \cdot (\lfloor \frac{p}{i} \rfloor \mod p)
$$

Comment: I missed one thing and edited the formula, can you check it again please?

Comment: $(-i)^{-1}i\equiv -1$ by multiplying the definition of multiplicative inverse by $-1$ .

Comment: How did you use that?

Comment: I was more showing a possible route.

Answer (score 0):

- $p\equiv 0\bmod p$
- $ i(i^{-1})\equiv 1\bmod p$
- $i\lfloor{p\over i}\rfloor\equiv -(p\bmod i)\bmod p$
- $-(p\bmod i)\cdot(p\bmod i)^{-1}\equiv -1\bmod p$

Partially screwed up my original thought. The only reason primes need to be invoked, is because you want the whole range $2,\ldots,p-1$ which is only a modular multiplicative group if $p$ is prime.