# Finding a number knowing the modular multiplicative inverse

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, inverse

Let a = 44 and m = 67
The modular multiplicative inverse of 'a' and 'm' is 32

```
i = inverseModFunction( a, m )
i = inverseModFunction( 44, 67 )
i = 32
```

It can be calculated here:
https://www.xarg.org/tools/modular-inverse-calculator/

Is there a way to find 'a' knowing the inverse modulo 'i' and 'm'?

```
i = 32
m = 67

a = function( i , m )
a = function( 32 , 67 )
a = ?
```

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm is what you are looking for.

Comment: If $i$ is inverse to $a$, then $a$ is inverse to $i$. (It seems that this is what you're asking about.) Just try plugging 32 and 67 into the calculator you linked.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
ai \equiv 1 \pmod{m}
\end{eqnarray*}
...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447954/by-knowing-1-1-1-mod-p-for-a-prime-p-why-can-we-obtain-multiplicative/3456525#3456525

Comment: **Hint** $ $ just like $\,-(-a) \equiv a\,$ we have $\color{#c00}{(a^{-1})^{-1}}\equiv a,\,$ by $\ i \equiv a^{-1}\!\!\iff ia \equiv 1\iff \color{#c00}{i^{-1}}\equiv a\ \ $

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modular inverse relation is symmetric, so if `i` is the modular inverse of `a`, then `a` is the modular inverse of `i` and can be found by `inverseModFunction(i,m)`.